# How to create an alias for multiple commands in ConEmu?

Tags: windows, alias, conemu

In Git-Bash I have an alias that executes two commands; update the list of branches for a git repository, then print them:

`alias glb='git remote update origin --prune && git branch -a'`

How do I do this in ConEmu? Specifically, [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) for Windows.

Since ConEmu doesn't use quotes with `alias`, I have to type `alias glb=git remote update origin --prune && git branch -a` which is interpreted as two separate commands, first `alias glb=git remote update origin --prune` and then `git branch -a`.

Comment: The answer depends on shell you are using and exact place where you are trying to configure alias

Comment: It's Cmder for Windows. I updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: I've asked about shell too! cmder is a terminal.

Comment: Actually, if you are using cmd.exe, you may just use double quotes instead of single ones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Command separator in ConEmu for me (on Windows) is:

`$t`

So your example would be:

`alias glb=git remote update origin --prune $t git branch -a`

**NOTE:** *Be sure to restart your conemu window or open a new tab in order for this to apply.* - thanks to @vetras for reminding me.

Reference: http://artandlogic.com/2013/06/making-the-windows-command-prompt-suck-slightly-less/

Comment: works but we need to close and start cmdr after we update the alias -- if we change the file on an editor. Took some time to get that.

Comment: You can get around having to restart CMDer simply by reloading the aliases via `alias /reload`. If for some reason that doesn't work, the full command is `%SystemRoot%\system32\doskey /macrofile=Path\To\Your\user-aliases.cmd`

Answer (score 3):

Open `user-aliases.cmd` file under \path\to\cmder\config to add the alias directly, then restart the cmder.

`glb=git remote update origin --prune $t git branch -a`